# not able to extract year from a dataframe column containing dates

Tags: python, pandas

HI I have a dataframe with a column containing dates (please see below). I want to extract years from each of them.

```
0     2017-01-25
1     2009-10-22
2     2015-10-21
3     2013-06-26
4     2018-05-16
5     2016-11-09
```

I tried using the formula

`df['year'] = (datetime.strptime(df['Date'], '%Y-%m-%d').year)`

but I get the below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series
```

How do I fix that?

Comment: _How do I fix that?_ That error seems rather clear to me, no? Have you done any debugging, any research? Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the whole column to the `datetime.strptime()` function.

What you want is to`.apply()` a function to each value of the `Date` column to get its  year, e.g.:

```
def get_year(x):
    return datetime.strptime(x, '%y-%m-%d').year

df['year'] = df.Date.apply(get_year)
```

Comment: thanks you are right I was passing the entire column which was the issue. I have condensed your answer in the lambda format as this   df1['year1'] = df1['EffectiveDate'].apply(lambda x:datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%M-%d').year)

Comment: Yeah @user13412850 I find lambda functions easier to type but harder to read. You can also use `df1.EffectiveDate`  instead of `df1['EffectiveDate']` to make it a little cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

If every single string in that column matches that date format then you don't even need use datetime here:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    Date = [
        '2017-01-25','2009-10-22','2015-10-21',
        '2013-06-26','2018-05-16','2016-11-09',
    ]
))

df['year'] = df['Date'].str.split('-',1,True)[0].astype(int)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
         Date  year
0  2017-01-25  2017
1  2009-10-22  2009
2  2015-10-21  2015
3  2013-06-26  2013
4  2018-05-16  2018
5  2016-11-09  2016
```

[example code in python tutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=import%20pandas%20as%20pd%0A%0Adf%20%3D%20pd.DataFrame%28dict%28%0A%20%20%20%20Date%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'2017-01-25','2009-10-22','2015-10-21',%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'2013-06-26','2018-05-16','2016-11-09',%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%29%29%0A%0Adf%5B'year'%5D%20%3D%20df%5B'Date'%5D.str.split%28'-',1,True%29%5B0%5D.astype%28int%29%0Aprint%28df%29&cumulative=true&curInstr=4&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=py3anaconda&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just convert the date and time and take out the year with `dt`.

```
 df['year'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d').dt.year
```